# When expressing a quantity, do the non-significant figures determine whether you round up the last significant figure?

Tags: significant-figures

I had thought that the non significant figures determined whether the least significant figure was to be rounded up. For example, given the number $9.1145$, if the number is to be expressed as three significant figures, then, I had thought that, it would be expressed as $9.12$.

However, I noticed that in one of my chemistry professor's calculations in which the quantities were expressed as significant to three figures, she expressed $8.125 \times 10^2$ as $813$. In another calculation she expressed $9.1145 \times 10^{-3}$ as $0.00911$. However, it seems to me that $0.00912$ is the correct expression of $9.1145 \times 10^{-3}$, as the $5$ requires rounding up the $4$, which requires rounding up the least significant $1$ to $2$.

Is there a rule for rounding that my professor is following that I don't know?

(Note: this isn't a homework question, but the homework tag seemed to be the most appropriate one.)

Comment: Never round twice. If that was the rule, then 0.46 could be rounded up to 1, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: [Relevant meta discussion](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2956/what-do-significant-figures-think-of-significant-figures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The international standard ISO 80000 *Quantities and units* – Part 1: *General* includes the normative Annex B *Rounding of numbers*, which stipulates:

> Rounding in more than one stage (…) may lead to errors. Therefore, the rounding shall always be carried out in only one step.
>
> Example: 12.254 should be rounded to 12.3 and not first to 12.25 and then to 12.2.

(Note that, in the given example, the ISO standard follows the *round half to even* rule in which the even multiple is selected as the rounded number. This is the default rounding mode for floating-point computation. Anyway, the rule “rounding shall always be carried out in only one step” is independent of the used tie-breaking rule.)